# Why does my Windows 3.10 only have chimes.wav, chord.wav and ding.wav, but no "Tada.wav"?

Tags: windows-3.x

After successfully installing Windows "3.10" in DOSBox-X, and finally getting the sound to work, I was confused to say the least to see that only these sound files exist on my installation:

```
chimes.wav
chord.wav
ding.wav
```

I wanted to hear the classic `Tada.wav` startup sound, as well as "The Shutdown Sound": `Xylophon.wav`. They can be heard here: https://www.winhistory.de/more/winstart/winstart_en.htm

I did not select some sort of "minimal" installation or anything of the sort.

This is really messing with my head and memories. Were these sounds not included in all language-versions of Windows 3.1x or something?

"winver" says "Windows 3.10", but the archive file says "Microsoft Windows 3.11 [Swedish].7z". The archive file doesn't include "virtual floppies", but instead just a bunch of files. I looked for countless hours but could not find a better or different copy of Windows 3.1x in Swedish anywhere online.

I can't remember whether I had 3.1, "3.10" (if that's different) or 3.11 back in the day. I don't think it was a "For Workgroups" edition. I vividly remember hearing the "Tada!" sound on a Windows 3.1x PC in the mid-1990s, although perhaps not at home. (I didn't have a sound card for the longest time, so I never noticed at home.)

I've looked for any information on this online, but from what I can tell, the actual floppies are supposed to include `Tada.wav` etc. Could it be that somebody manually deleted that file before making that archive? Or perhaps selected a "minimal" installation when they installed it originally and that sound was excluded as a result?

Of course, I could copy a `Tada.wav` into my installation, but this makes me wonder *what else* might be missing, and why it's missing in the first place.

Comment: @StephenKitt I wonder what determined whether these were shipped.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why are there no actual complete and 100% verified/vetted ROM collections still?](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/16478/why-are-there-no-actual-complete-and-100-verified-vetted-rom-collections-still)

Comment: @Peter (guessing based on big-company experience) - separate dev teams for 'localized' versions, desynchronized release schedules, accidental omissions, hitting floppy disk capacity, ...

Answer (score 9):

`TADA.WAV` shipped with Windows 3.10 (not for Workgroups); you can see it for example in the list of files shipped on the disks, shown on [PCjs](https://www.pcjs.org/software/pcx86/sys/windows/3.10/)’s catalog.

Windows for Workgroups 3.11, which I suspect is what you have, only shipped `CHIMES.WAV`, `DING.WAV`, `RINGIN.WAV` and `RINGOUT.WAV` (as far as I can determine). `WINVER.EXE` in that version of Windows identifies itself as Windows 3.10; to distinguish between the various versions you can look at the strings in `SYSTEM/KRNL386.EXE`.

Regarding your question about versions of Windows, there were the following versions of Windows 3.1*x*:

- Windows 3.10;
- Windows 3.10 for Workgroups, the first Workgroups release;
- Windows 3.11, which was a downloadable upgrade for Windows 3.10 (`WW0981.EXE` from the Microsoft Software Library);
- Windows 3.11 for Workgroups, which had a significant number of non-networking-related improvements (32-bit file access for example).